# Random parameter for FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

Here I have a `StatefulWidget` in which I want to get a random pet each time from a random url. Also, I have a condition for the random pet, if the condition is true, the pet will be shown, otherwise the random url and random pet should be selected again. I attached my code below, and the problem is the url only changes when the condition is false, but I want it to be randomly selected each time.

Putting the `API.get_pets(init_random_url);` in the `future` parameter of the `FutureBuilder` will solve the random selection but if the condition is false the URL and the pet would change two or three times, after searching about it and reading `FutureBuilder` documentation I put it in the `initState` and `requestAgain` and `build`, but I recognized the selectedURL in the `build` function does not work and the widget is stucked in the same URL until the condition gets false value.

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:double_back_to_close/toast.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pet_store/widgets/guess_game_random_card.dart';
import 'webservice/API.dart';
import 'main.dart';
import 'dart:math';
import 'utils/utils.dart';

Random random = new Random();

class Guess_Game extends StatefulWidget {
  const Guess_Game({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Guess_Game> createState() => _Guess_GameState();
}

class _Guess_GameState extends State<Guess_Game> {

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init_random_url = randomly_select_URL();
    GuessGameFuture = API.get_pets(init_random_url);
  }

  void requestAgain() {
    setState(() {
      init_random_url = randomly_select_URL();
      GuessGameFuture = API.get_pets(init_random_url);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    init_random_url = randomly_select_URL();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: 
              FutureBuilder<List<dynamic>>(
                future: GuessGameFuture,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {

                    List<dynamic>? pet_data = snapshot.data;
                      var number_of_parameters = snapshot.data!.length;
                      var random_pet = random.nextInt(number_of_parameters);
                      var category = pet_data![random_pet].category.toString();
                      var photoURL = pet_data![random_pet].photoUrls;
                      // Here is the condition that ensure pet category is in the list and has an image
                      if (checkCategoryInList(category, items) &&
                          photoURL.length != 0) {
                        return Random_Card(
                            pet_data: pet_data,
                            random_pet: random_pet,
                            dropdownvalue: dropdownvalue);
                      } else {
                        if (photoURL.length == 0) {
                          print(" NO PHOTO SUBMITTED FOR THIS PET");
                        } else {
                          print(category + "NOT IN CATEGORY");
                        }
                        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                          requestAgain();
                        });
                      }
                    
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("${snapshot.error}");
                  }
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              )
            else
              const Text(
                "Please select your guess",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, color: Colors.indigo),
              ),
        ),
      ),
    
  }
}
```

Comment: I think, something is missing here. `init_random_url ` should be a property of your State class

Comment: Am I understanding correctly, that you want the image to change each time you reload the page? In that case, you should insert a line of `GuessGameFuture = API.get_pets(init_random_url);` in the second line of your build method.

Comment: @JoRa I tried this solution but it is not generating a random URL for the `FutureBuilder`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to build

`GuessGameFuture = API.get_pets(randomly_select_URL());`

and Change requestAgain function to this:

```
  void requestAgain() {
    setState(() {
      GuessGameFuture = API.get_pets(randomly_select_URL());
    });
  }
```

Also you can use `FutureProvider` and `riverpod` library.
Hope it helps